# Button can't be pressed twice

Tags: html, css

Why button '1' can be pressed only one time? after the first click it won't respond.  it happened after I added height=100% , but I still can't understand why.

The Javascript is for additional buttons that I'm planning to add.

Thanks for everyone that can help!

```
<html>
<head>
<style>

html,body
{
height: 100%;
}
body {
background-color: white;
width: 960px;
margin: auto;
position: relative;
}

.one {
background-color:blue;
color: black;
font-size: 45px;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
overflow:hidden;
float:left;
position:absolute;
transition: .5s ease;
top: 250px;
left: 240px;
text-align: center;
}
.one:hover {
-webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
transform: scale(1.1);
color: #21211e;
font-size: 45px;
vertical-align: center;
}

.overlay {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);;
transition: opacity 500ms;
visibility: hidden;
opacity: 0;
z-index:0;
}

.overlay:target {
visibility: visible;
opacity: 1;
}

.popup {
margin: 70px auto;
padding: 20px;
background: #fff;
border-radius: 5px;
width: 30%;
position: relative;
transition: all 5s ease-in-out;
}

.popup h2 {
margin-top: 0;
color: #333;
font-family: Tahoma, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.popup .close {
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
right: 30px;
transition: all 200ms;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: none;
color: #333;
}

.popup .close:hover {
color: orange;
}

.popup .content {
max-height: 30%;
overflow: auto;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<a class="one" id="one" href="#popup1" onclick="changeZIndex(this)">1</a>
<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
<div class="popup">
    <h2>Here i am</h2>
    <a class="close" href="#">×</a>
    <div class="content">
        1
    </div>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function changeZIndex(elm) {
    if (elm.className == "one") {
        document.getElementById('one').style.zIndex = -1;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it seems to work here: http://jsfiddle.net/swm53ran/355/ if your desired functionality was to click `1` and have a modal popup with an overlay, then once you exit the popup, `1` can be clicked again.

Comment: It still not works for me at my browser, how can it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are seeing here is a Z-index thing. Essentially, you can see the button but you are mousing over the object in front of it. For a link to be clickable it can't be covered by something with a lower Z-index.

Comment: But the issue came up after adding 'height=100%; , if I'll delete it, it works perfect.

Comment: Without giving `html` and `body` a height of 100%, they effectively have no vertical dimension because the only content is positioned absolutely and does not register. As soon as you do add it, the click will make it so that the element becomes placed beneath `body` itself. I'm sure the poster of this answer means "covered by something with a *higher* z-index" by the way.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so is there any way to make it works with keeping java code?

Comment: I didn't quite state that correctly though, the button is placed beneath `#popup1` first and then `body`. Not sure I get exactly what you're after but I assume something similar to this : http://jsfiddle.net/9zz97ovu. The parent container places all content above `body` - but inside it the overlay is one level lower than the button.

Comment: Glad to help out of course. There's likely a slightly shorter way of coding it but I just added the z-indexes on all elements to demonstrate. I'm a bit confused about it myself even while fiddling with it some more - stacking contexts can be that way, they're quite complicated.